# pageX value not updating in touchmove function

Tags: javascript, touchstart, touchmove

I'm trying to move an element on the page using the `pageX` value of a touch event. I put two `console.log` statements in the code below to track the `pageX` value - the first outputs the `pageX` value in the `touchstart` function, and the second continuously tracks the `pageX` value within the `touchmove` function as my finger is moved across the screen.

I'm expecting the `pageX` value from the `touchmove` function to change continuously as I'm moving my finger, but it's just continuously outputting the same thing that the `touchstart` function output. For instance, if the output of the `touchstart` `console.log` is `256.55` for the `pageX` value, then the `touchmove` `console.log` will just continuously output a stream of the value `256.55`, which is where I would expect this value to change.

I've tried removing the `event.preventDefault();` statement, which is just sort of a guess as to something that would prevent `pageX` from updating? But that didn't change anything.

Is the `pageX` value even the right value to track for continuous x position?

```
// event listener on an image that gets touched
lightboxImages[i].addEventListener('touchstart', touchMove);

  function touchMove(event) {

    console.log(touch.pageX);

    event.preventDefault();
    var touchedImage = event.target;
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    var moveOffsetX = touchedImage.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;

    touchedImage.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {

      console.log(touch.pageX);

      var positionX = touch.pageX + moveOffsetX;
      touchedImage.style.left = positionX + 'px';
    }, false);
  }
```

Most of this code taken from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3b1rvuFCJY

**EDIT: I've refactored the code into two separate functions, like this:**

```
// event listeners on an image that gets touched
lightboxImages[i].addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
lightboxImages[i].addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);

function touchStart(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    touchedImage = event.target;
    touch = event.touches[0];
    moveOffsetX = touchedImage.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;

    console.log(touch.pageX);

  }

  function touchMove(event) {

    console.log(touch.pageX);

    var positionX = touch.pageX + moveOffsetX;
    //touchedImage.style.left = positionX + 'px';
    touchedImage.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';

  }
```

..but still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Why do you have quotes in console.log? I would place the touchmove listener outside of the other listener, because now you will keep adding eventlisteners on top of each other...

Comment: sorry, I typed it wrong - not actually like that in the code. I edited.

Comment: @Kokodoko yeah I read a comment on the youtube page about the `touchmove` event being inside the `touchstart` function.. should I try declaring both event listeners the same? I'll update my question to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that assigning `touchstart`'s `pageX` value to a variable does not get changed within `touchmove`, so I had to just assign `touchmove`'s `event.touches[0]` to its own variable, like so:

```
function touchStart(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    touchedImage = event.target;
    touch = event.touches[0];
    moveOffsetX = touchedImage.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;

  }

  function touchMove(event) {

    // rather than trying to access variable touch from the touchstart function, I had to get event.touches[0] from touchmove's event
    var movedTouch = event.touches[0];

    var positionX = movedTouch.pageX + moveOffsetX;
    touchedImage.style.left = positionX + 'px';

  }
```